# jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using a jquery pluggin for a quick and easy [form validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) My forms use the input's default value as a label and I have a little onfocus and onblur javascript function to show and hide this when the user starts to type:

```
<input name='fnameREG' type='text' id='fnameREG' value='first name' size='70' onfocus='clearInput(this)' onblur='clearInput(this)' />
<input name='lnameREG' type='text' id='lnameREG' value='last name' size='70' onfocus='clearInput(this)' onblur='clearInput(this)' />
```

My issue with the validation is that when the submit button is clicked the pluggin thinks that all the fields are set because they have a default value. I looked but I couldn't find a supplied method to get round this. Thanks!
...Or has anyone come accross a better validation method?

And here is the .addmethod function for the pluggin which I am trying unsucessfuly to use to add a new method that checks for the default value. Any ideas???

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("deflt", function(value, element) { 
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.defaultValue; 
    }, "You must enter a value");
```

Mark... below is my clearInput function. Yea it basically does the same as the watermark effect but I'm using this now and can't see much reason to switch. Although if I don't find another way I will use this, it would just involve deleting some markup:

```
function clearInput(field){
    if (field.defaultValue == field.value){
        field.value = '';
    }
    else if (field.value == ''){
        field.value = field.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would still be inclined to use the watermark than write your own validation function. You'll end up writing more and more validation methods to account for the default value (e.g. defltRegex). The watermark will work with whatever validation methods you use and it will let you style the watermark to make it look like instruction rather than an actual default value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what `clearInput` does, but are you looking for a watermark effect?

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I do on a client's site:

```
var default_values = new Array();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.inputStyle, textarea").focus(function() {
        if(!default_values[this.id]) {
            default_values[this.id] = this.value;
        }
        if(this.value == default_values[this.id]) this.value = '';
    });
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var error_queue = new Array();
        var errMessage = 'Please fill out the following fields:\n  + ';
        $("input.inputStyle, textarea").each(function(i) {
            if(!default_values[this.id]) {
                default_values[this.id] = this.value;
            }
            if(this.value == '' || this.value == default_values[this.id])
                error_queue[error_queue.length] = default_values[this.id];
        });
        if(error_queue.length > 0) {
            alert(errMessage + error_queue.join('\n  + '));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still looking to get this pluggin working, I always figure that the less code/markup thats involved the better

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("deflt", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || value == element.defaultValue; 
}, "You must enter a value");
```

"value" should be just the string value of the element, thus it would not have a "defaultValue" property, but "element" might have a "defaultValue"